# EJB Injection failure on deploy

Tags: glassfish, ejb, code-injection

I've got a problem exxh EJB's.

First of all, my setup: I am using GlassFish & JEE6. I have got a REST-Service packaged as a WAR and a bean packaged as an EJB-Jar. They are not inside an EAR.
The EJB should be used from the REST-WAR via @EJB, but when I try to deploy the WAR, GlassFish shows this error:

Error occurred during deployment:

```
Exception while deploying the app [exx-upload-1.0] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=com.ex.exx.model.FileUpload/ocr,Local 3.x interface =com.ex.exx.api.IOCRService,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session. Please see server.log for more details.
```

(The EJB was deployed before without any erros).

I have no clue why. Here is the EJB Code:

Interface:

```
@Local
public interface IOCRService {
    public String performOCRonImage(BufferedImage input);
}
```

and Implementation:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class OCRScanner implements IOCRService  {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private final static String NOT_RECOGNIZED = "Can not regocnize text";
    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public OCRScanner() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "### OCR SCANNER BUILD" + this);
    }



    public String performOCRonImage(BufferedImage input) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "### OCR SCANNER CALLED" + this);
    }

    ...
```

And here is the important part in the WAR:

```
public class FileUpload {
private final File PROPERTIES_FILE = new File(
        "fileUploadProperties.properties");
private final String PARAMETER_NAME = "file";
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());


@EJB
private IOCRService ocr;

public Response uploadFile(...) {
    // do some stuff
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "### EJB" + ocr.toString())
}
```

Anny suggestions? I can not find my failure here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this, by replaceing @Local with @Remote.
This works, however, I am not satisfied as I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, given the specs (eg. explained in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm#GIPIZ)), an application can only access other application's EJB, if they are decorated with `@Remote`.

Thus, you have 3 options:

1. decorate your EJB with `@Remote` (what you have done),
2. package both together inside an ear (as they would reside in the
   same application then). But if you intent to deploy them in seperate
   applications or even seperate servers, use 1.)
3. use CDI with `@Inject`, but this will still only discover the EJB if
   either in the same application, or decorated as `@Remote` if not.

HTH,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `@EJB` if the target is not an EJB. I guess this is your case because you are trying to inject into a class in your WAR.

Instead use:

```
@Inject
private IOCRService ocr;
```

Basically, `@Inject` is better in most cases, because:

- it is more typesafe,
- it supports @Alternatives
- it is aware of the scope of the injected object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is an EJB. Solved my problem in another way, will post the response in a while

Answer (score -1):

Another solution it's to add `@Stateless(name="")`, this worked form